# How to assign or add a list of json results to a variable array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

Good day!

I'm not quite exposed with client-side scripting like javascript so I wanted to learn how to assign or even add sets of values to a javascript variable array. I understand that if you have to assign values manually it looks like this

```
var data = [{
            name: 'charlie',
            com:'lkdhls dfjgldkg kfldg kdlfngldlf',
            id: 1
        }, {
            name: 'mark',
            com: 'lkdhls dfjgldkg kfldg kdlfngldlf erttre',
            id: 2
        }, {
            name: 'darrell',
            com: 'lkdhls dfjgldkg kfldg ',
            id: 3
        }, {
            name: 'rick',
            com: 'lkdhls dfjgldkg kfldg kdlfngldlf',
            id: 4
        }, {
            name: 'heather',
            com: 'lkdhls dfjgldkg kfldg kdlfngldlf ertwtrrb ryryre',
            id: 5
        }];
```

Now my question is, how do I assign or add values to this **var data = [];** coming from my json result like this?

```
          var data =[];

            $.getJSON('/controller/method', null, function (result) {

           // from here I want to insert the result to data variable so I can call it to my next function
            });
```

How do I do this? Thanks...

Comment: Use `push()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push. Although, can you not amend the returned JSON to be in that format?

Comment: `unshift()` can also be used, based on where data should be added. Also based on what the `result` is you will need to do some extra manipulations with it.

Comment: Adding to @rory comment, `data.push.apply(data , result)` or `data = data.concat(result);`

Comment: @timmack how does result look like??  it should be already array, you can simple assign `data  = result`

Comment: Thanks for all your comment but after assigning the json results to the variable array. Can we also call that variable in the other functions holding the values of the same json results that were assigned?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I want the Json result to be in that format if possible. Can we?